# Prove that $G$ is an infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I have posted a proof below and would appreciate it if someone could review my solution. Thanks!

> Prove that if $A = \{1,2,3,...\}$, where $A$ is the natural numbers, then S$_A$ is an infinite group.

Proof:

Let $A = \{1,2,3,...\}$. 
Then $S_A$ is the set of all permutations of $A$. 
$S_A$ is clearly non empty since it is a group.

Then suppose $S_A$ was finite. 
Let $P = \{p_1, p_2, \cdots , p_n \}$ where $p_i$ is an element of $S_A$ and $P$ contains all elements of $S_A$.

Then let $x = 1$. Let $J = \{ p_i(x)\ |\ p_i \in P\}$. Then $J$ is finite since $P$ is finite and so $J$ has a max value that is attained in $J$. Take some $y\gt j$ for all $j \in J$. Then define the bijection $f(1) = y$ and $f(y) = 1$, and the identity map for all other input values for $f$. The cycle decomposition would be: $(1\ y)$.

Then $f$ is permutation that is not contained in $P$ since no permutation in $P$ maps $1 \to y$. Hence we have a contradiction that $P$ is the set of all permutations from $A \to A$.

Hence $S_A$ cannot be finite. Hence $S_A$ must be infinite.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Have you proven that given any set, the collection of all permutations on a set form a group? Because if you have, then your first line is fine (though it’s easier to simply exhibit the identity as an element of the set), but if you haven’t, then it is no.

Comment: As you say, there are infinitely many transpositions $(1\,y)$ in $S_A$. That's enough to show $S_A$ is infinite; one needn't try to argue by contradiction.

Comment: I would note that you don’t have a proof by contradiction, you have a “proof by fake contradiction.” You are actually showing that given any finite subset $X$ of $S_A$, there is an element of $S_A$ that is not in $X$. This proves that $S_A$ is infinite.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes the book has proven that S$_B$ for any set B forms a group and I was using the fact that a group must have an identity element... on ur second comment, would the use of a contradiction be technically wrong or just needless? i read it as still correct, though the comment above yours shows that u can simply construct an infinite set with greater ease... wouldnt ur explanation rely on a contradiction as well though? you are stating that if S$_A$ was finite, it would not contain all the elements it should have. contradiction

Comment: The contradiction is useless. You have a proof that $A$ implies $B$. But you phrase it by saying “Suppose $B$ is false.” Then you write down the proof that $A$ implies $B$, without *ever* using the fact that you are assuming $B$ to be false. Then at the end you say “But this contradicts our assumption that $B$ is false. Therefore $B$ is true.” You can do that with **any** proof, but it is just needless complications.  What the argument you have is: “no finite subset is the whole thing.” There is no argument by contradiction involved. It’s the contrapositive of “is infinite”.

Comment: on "no finite subset is the whole thing". I agree, and would the whole argument be: "since no finite set can contain all of S$_A$, then S$_A$ cannot be finite. Since S$_A$ is not finite, it must be infinite since it is also nonempty." .... I suppose that would be as direct as it gets, correct?  @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Except, of course, that the empty set is finite, so “since it is also nonempty” is not required.

Comment: I establish that any finite group does not contain all of S$_A$, hence it is not equal to S$_A$ -- a contradiction to what I supposed. When I conclude that any finite group does not contain all of S$_A$, you COULD also conclude that S$_A$ is not finite. However, in my proof I do not go this route and instead use a contradiction to what I supposed to derive this fact. Hence there is no direct proof inside my original proof, but it IS one EASY addition from being a direct proof.  @ArturoMagidin, thoughts?

Comment: You assume $S_A$ is finite. Now tell me, before you reach your contradiction, **where did you use that assumption**? Answer: Nowhere. You took a finite set, but the fat that you assumed it was all of $S_A$ is **never used** until you exhibit this assumption to contradict your construction of an element outside your finite set. (Where you write “group”, you should write “subset”). So, no, you are still not understanding my point. (cont)

Comment: Take your statement “Let $P=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ be a subset of $S_A$.” (Don’t assume it is all of $S_A$; you never use that). Now take your next paragraph as-is. Now take your next sentence, “Then $f$ is a permutation that is not contained in $P$, since no permutation in $P$ maps $1$ to $y$.” **That** is a direct proof that given any finite subset $P$ of $S_A$, $P$ is not all of $S_A$. You **never** use the fact that $P$ is assumed to be all of $S_A$ until *after* that final sentence I quote. It never goes into the construction. It is not needed, except to exhibit at the end. (cont)

Comment: So what you have is: (i) an embedded argument that $A\implies B$. (ii) An addition of the statement “Assume not($B$)” at the top. (iii) An addition of the statement “But this contradicts our assumption of not($B$)” at the end. The additions are irrelevant to the proof.

Comment: I show that P is not all of S$_A$. I am using "S$_A$ is finite" but I don't draw any further conclusions from it in the usual sense. Supposing "S$_A$ is finite" is true leads to a contradiction itself without any additional derivations from supposing its true. Its a 1 step contradiction argument. Your direct proof ends with "P is not all of S$_A$". I view it as my job to state the last (easy) step that S$_A$ is not finite. To do this I can just point out a contradiction if someone were to claim that P = S$_A$ is finite. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: the contradiction being that P cannot equal S$_A$.

Comment: You **never** use the assumption that $P$ is all of $S_A$ until after you conclude that $P$ is not all of $S_A$. That means that the assumption that $P$ is all of $S_A$ is *irrelevant* and *useless* to your proof. You are not doing a proof by contradiction, you are confusing yourself into thinking you are doing a proof by contradiction. You do not merely not draw conclusion from your extra assumption “in the usual sense”, you draw no conclusions from it **at all**. All you do is add an unnecessary hypothesis at the top, so that you can add an unnecessary statement at the bottom.

Comment: That doesn’t make the argument *wrong*, it just makes it unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: Look, it’s the exact same issue that occurs in most common published proofs of Euclid’s theorem of the infinitude of primes, and Cantor’s diagonal proof that the reals are uncountable. They are almost always cast as a proof by contradiction, when in fact they are a direct proof of “no finite set of primes contains all primes” and “no list of reals contains all reals”. For some reason, people, especially beginners, fall in love with proofs by contradiction, and use them even when they are not needed. It’s a good exercise to learn to recognize when you aren’t really using the extra hypothesis.

Comment: So I conclude that "P is not all of S$_A$" and then use that to contradict the statement that "P, some finite set, is  S$_A$". So yes you're right. I guess I just use the (needless) contradiction to put the argument into its final words ie "S$_A$ is not finite", I'm not sure why I find it easier to think about it that way, though I have a feeling that using it gives me and maybe others an extra sense of security they have the correct idea. Thanks for the patience!

Comment: I would agree theres a personal preference for proofs by contradiction. Theres something cool about figuring something out via sort of an unconventional means

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93215/discussion-between-h-1317-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: if I proved finite implies not S$_A$, then I just proved the contrapositive of the following statement: if you have the set S$_A$ then it is infinite. correct? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: I have no interest in continuing a conversation that ended 3 weeks ago, nor the time to re-familiarize myself with it. I am sure I said everything I wanted to say at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is correct, but it would be more natural and simpler to note that, if $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$, the permutation $(1\ \ n)$ belongs to $S_A$. Therefore, $S_A$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes, as was pointed out before in a comment by Lord Shark the Unknown.